# How to fix conversion error from InnoDB to MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, myisam, alter-table

How can I fix conversion error from InnoDB to MyISAM for these tables?

```
MariaDB [db_name]> ALTER TABLE wp_posts ENGINE = MyISAM;
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
MariaDB [db_name]> ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ENGINE = MyISAM;
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

```
+-------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table             | Non_unique | Key_name                                              | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| wp_posts |          0 | PRIMARY                                               |            1 | ID             | A         |      419351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | post_name                                             |            1 | post_name      | A         |      419351 |      191 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | type_status_date                                      |            1 | post_type      | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | type_status_date                                      |            2 | post_status    | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | type_status_date                                      |            3 | post_date      | A         |      419351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | type_status_date                                      |            4 | ID             | A         |      419351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | post_parent                                           |            1 | post_parent    | A         |      419351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | post_author                                           |            1 | post_author    | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_modified                   |            1 | post_modified  | A         |      419351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_type_post_statu_post_type  |            1 | post_type      | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_type_post_statu_post_type  |            2 | post_status    | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_type_post_statu_post_type  |            3 | post_mime_type | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_type_post_passw_post_statu |            1 | post_type      | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_type_post_passw_post_statu |            2 | post_password  | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_type_post_passw_post_statu |            3 | post_status    | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_type_post_statu_id         |            1 | post_type      | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_type_post_statu_id         |            2 | post_status    | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_type_post_statu_id         |            3 | ID             | A         |      419351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_posts |          1 | wp_posts_idx_post_date                       |            1 | post_date      | A         |      419351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| ID                    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| post_author           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| post_date             | datetime            | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_date_gmt         | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_content          | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_title            | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_excerpt          | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_status           | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | publish             |                |
| comment_status        | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | open                |                |
| ping_status           | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | open                |                |
| post_password         | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| post_name             | varchar(200)        | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| to_ping               | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| pinged                | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_modified         | datetime            | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_modified_gmt     | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_content_filtered | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_parent           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| guid                  | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| menu_order            | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| post_type             | varchar(20)         | NO   | MUL | post                |                |
| post_mime_type        | varchar(100)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| comment_count         | bigint(20)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

```
+----------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                | Non_unique | Key_name                                | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| wp_postmeta |          0 | PRIMARY                                 |            1 | meta_id     | A         |     3777303 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_postmeta |          1 | post_id                                 |            1 | post_id     | A         |     1259101 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_postmeta |          1 | wp_postme_idx_meta_key_post_id |            1 | meta_key    | A         |       23906 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_postmeta |          1 | wp_postme_idx_meta_key_post_id |            2 | post_id     | A         |     3777303 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| meta_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| meta_key   | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meta_value | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16568369/470530) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-limits.html) - InnoDBs index limit is bigger than MyISAM's! You obviously have indexes which are too big for MyISAM. What I'd like to know is **why on earth** are you moving to an engine which is deprecated? You'll have to redesign your system what's more!

Comment: @Vérace lol, hi, thx a lot. i cant deal with the required ram amount of the innodb, 6.8gb innodb size requires much more space to store it in the memory which i cant handle to pay right now. Using a server with 3.7gb memory.

Comment: the entire database doesn't need to go to innodb buffer pool, only the active stuff that is frequently used/modified. MyISAM will work the same way with the inactive pages not being in the linux kernel page cache.

Comment: Maybe your meta_key can be reduced to the maximum size used (also the smallest character set used). Can you use `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` as this includes datatypes in an easier to read format.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: @danblack i removed the indexes that i created for extra, now im able to convert them.

Comment: I see you still haven't remove [password](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266741/error-1071-42000-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes) that was unused in your last question.

Comment: @danblack which tables can i use with innodb engine btw for speaking wordpress?
wp_posts and wp_postsmeta my 2 largest sized tables. Well im definetly not thinking about to use them with innodb. And im a rookie whick makes me unable to remove password stuff lol.

Comment: Lift the hood/bonnet of your car.  Remove anything that you don't recognize.  Now see if the car still functions!  `wp_posts` contains everything you wrote; you can't get rid if it!

Answer (score 2):

NO!  That's the wrong solution to a memory issue.

The buffer_pool is a "cache"; it does not have to be bigger than the dataset.

InnoDB is faster than MyISAM; this point, alone, may doom your conversion to disaster.

The 1000 comes from 4*255, where the 4 comes from using `ut8mb4` (good) and WP's default of using `VARCHAR(255)` (not good).  Check your data, probably you come no where near to using 255 characters in any of those columns.  Or maybe sometimes you have exceed 255 and had the data silently truncated!.

Here are tips on speeding up postmeta and making it smaller:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Another bulky thing that WP unnecessarily does: BIGINT (8 bytes) for lots of columns.  A 4-byte INT (2 billion max) would save a lot of space.  (But that is rather tedious to fix.

For the main performance boost (Caveat: I have not verified it):

```
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key),
    ADD INDEX(meta_id) ;
```

Comment: How can i convert
```CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta (
meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
post_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
meta_key varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
meta_value longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (meta_id),
KEY post_id (post_id),
KEY meta_key (meta_key)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;```
to this
```CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta (
post_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
meta_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
meta_value LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key),
INDEX(meta_key)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;```

Comment: Do a dump. Change all the engines that you want - substitute `Engine=MyISAM` for `Engine=InnoDB` for the relevant tables and then restore the (modified) dump! However, you have been told that this change is not a good idea - very few databases fit entirely in RAM - they're not meant to and systems such as MySQL have been designed with this in mind!

Comment: @execash - I added the `ALTER`.

Comment: @Vérace - his comment is about the change to postmeta, not about switching to MyISAM.

Comment: Ooops! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @RickJames ```PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key)``` has plenty duplicates, so i went for the next one. I tried the softwares that i downloaded before which are mySQL Workbench and Sequel Pro. However i cant add ```PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key, meta_id)``` now, it looks like my /tmp is getting out of space and i get this ```ERROR 1034 (HY000): Index for table 'wp_postmeta' is corrupt; try to repair it.``` Also im not able to edit this (remove DEFAULT '') ```  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''``` Rest is all set.

Comment: @execash - You are out of disk space, too?  That's a more serious problem.  And even if you get past it today, it will bite you tomorrow.  Consider getting a bigger server.

Comment: @execash - and...   MyISAM has a habit of ending up with "corrupt" indexes (InnoDB is self-fixing); use `CHECK TABLE` and `REPAIR TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames naw i got enough space on /sda1 but the prompt keeps tryin for /tmp partition which has limited size. im with innodb, used --force the rebuild them but not working. Growth the server 1vcpu 6.5gb ram.

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_name`.`wp_postmeta` (
  `post_id,meta_key,meta_id` VARCHAR(295) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id,meta_key,meta_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;```

I find out the above one still im getting error. I think it might happen because of the character amount.
@RickJames ```post_id BIGINT(20)  + meta_key VARCHAR(255) + meta_id BIGINT(20) = 20+255+20 = VARCHAR(295) lol if this is the math?``` Anyway code turns back with a warning and im not able to create PRIMARY KEY once again.

Comment: @execash - BIGINT is 8 bytes; the `(20)` means nothing.  `utf8mb4` takes up to 4 _bytes_ per _character_.  So, 4*255+8+8 > 1000.